# winston save logs to file only when debugging

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, logging, winston

I'm using winston in my express app.
When I run the app with `node app.js` winston log only to the console,
but if I run the app with VSCode debugger- it logs also to the error.log file as he should.

I'm using winston v2.3.1, can't upgrade.

my code:

```
const logger = new winston.Logger({
transports : [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    new winston.transports.File({
        filename : './app/error.log',
        handleExceptions: true,
        humanReadableUnhandledException: true
        })
   ], 
handleExceptions : true
});
```